# Find the index of combobox item using object value

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox bound to a data source "StatusListBindingSource" with Status and StatusID. I need the index of the found item. I'll use the index to set `Me.cmbResult.SelectedIndex`

This works fine except I don't want to use a for/each loop:

```
Private Sub SetStatusIndex(ByVal StatusValue As Integer)
    Dim ItemIndex As Integer = -1
    Dim ct As Integer = 0
    For Each dView As DataRowView In Me.cmbResult.Items
        If dView.Row.Item("StatusID") = StatusValue Then
            ItemIndex = ct
            Exit For
        End If
        ct += 1
    Next
    Me.cmbResult.SelectedIndex = ItemIndex
End Property
```

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
Dim a As ComboBox.ObjectCollection = Me.cmbResult.Items

'can't cast like this
Dim lisDRView As List(Of DataRowView) = a.Cast(Of DataRowView)()

'I'd like to use something like .find
Dim drView As DataRowView = lisDRView.Find(Function(x) x.Row.Item("StatusID") = StatusValue)

'there is no drView.index so this fails
Me.cmbResult.SelectedIndex = drView.index
```

But I'm getting an exception on `a.Cast(Of DataRowView)()` and of course there's no `drView.index`

> invalidcastexception: 
>   Unable to cast object 
>   of type 'd__aa'1[System.Data.DataRowView]' 
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRowView]'.

How do I get the index of the item with given StatusValue using find?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Dim lis As List(Of DataRowView) = _
        (From item As DataRowView In cmbResult.Items Select item).ToList
Dim d = lis.Find(Function(x As DataRowView) x.Row.Item("StatusID") = StatusValue)
Me.cmbResult.SelectedItem = d
```

With an assist from [how to get the all combobox item .... using array](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/277959/how-to-get-the-all-combobox-item-using-array)